# Error when exporting reports to a PDF

Tags: drupal, pdf, printing

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
>   moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
>   with more details about what action you were performing when this
>   occurred. The file '/tmp/knp_snappy5b68b75c2e47a.pdf' was not created
>   (command: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh --lowquality --margin-bottom '1in'
>   --margin-left '1in' --margin-right '1in' --margin-top '1in' --orientation 'landscape' --page-height '792pt' --page-width '612pt' '/tmp/knp_snappy5b68b75c2e3a2.html'
>   '/tmp/knp_snappy5b68b75c2e47a.pdf').

Someone else had the same problem on [this forum](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=34247.0.html) and was able to solve it by removing `proc_open` from disabled modules in the php.ini. Mine however makes no mention of `proc_open`.

I checked that `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh` exists and the Drupal status report shows, working:

> Printer, email and PDF versions - PDF generation library  wkhtmltopdf
>   0.12.4

Does anyone have experience with [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) with CiviCRM and know how to resolve this error?

I am using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.3.1 with Linux and Apache.

When I run the command manually, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: 183: /usr/bin/xvfb-run: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found
```

Here are the contents of the `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh` Script:

```
#! /bin/sh
/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf $*
```

Comment: What happens if you run the command in the message manually?  You may need to substitute your own html file if the temporary one has gone.

Comment: I get /usr/bin/xvfb-run: 183: /usr/bin/xvfb-run: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found; even when I substitute for my own test html file in the tmp dir.

Comment: Just to check, you are running '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh ...' but it is complaining about '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf' (no .sh), Where is your wkhtmltopdf binary?

Comment: Correct, when I run the command manually. Is the binary different than the `usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh` file?

Comment: This seems weird, do you know why it's doing that?